# High Load Average but Low CPU Usage

Tags: redhat, top, rhel8

I'm trying to find the cause of the high load average on our server running in RHEL 8. The top command shows that our load average for 1, 5, and 15 is more than 250+. Also, server is responsive at the moment and no issues when running any jobs or command in the server. How can I identify what's causing the high load average on the server?

```
top - 20:30:34 up 158 days, 20:38, 117 users,  load average: 252.86, 252.44, 252.99
Tasks: 4317 total,   2 running, 4169 sleeping, 142 stopped,   4 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.4 us,  0.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.5 id,  0.1 wa,  0.1 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 514062.8 total,  46031.5 free, 149357.7 used, 318673.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap: 524288.0 total, 489689.0 free,  34598.9 used. 354115.2 avail Mem
```

Comment: What is the result of command `vmstat 1 3`?

Comment: This is what I got:

`procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 3  0 35350988 55057024   9500 318950016    0    0     0     7    0    0  3  1 96  0  0
 3  0 35350988 55043336   9500 318952832    0    0     0     0 51671 97756  3  0 97  0  0
 6  0 35350988 55032984   9500 318954784    0    0     0     0 53597 103855  3  0 97  0  0`

Comment: Add this in question, not as comment

Comment: Share the result of the following command.

`top` or `htop` or `htop -t`

follow the link manual to install the command if it's not already installed https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/server/linux/how-to-install-and-use-htop/

Answer (score -1):

The issue was due to the ghost vnc sessions we have in the server including the root account. After killing those processes, the load average went back to normal.